# How to select all text up to the cursor?

Tags: text, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I occasionally look through logs or other data where I'm only interested in a small piece of a very large amount of data. I usually just drop it into sublime text and then cut out all the data I'm not interested in. How can I select all the text from the beginning up to my cursor? And all the text from my cursor to the end of the file? That would make reviewing data a little easier. I'd prefer if this answer worked in sublime text 3, but other lightweight text editors would be useful too if it couldn't be done if sublime text 3.

Comment: controll+shift+home

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Mac:

Select all text **above** your cursor: `command+shift+up`.

Select all text **below** your cursor: `command+shift+down`.

## Windows:

Select all text **above** your cursor: `ctrl+shift+home`.

Select all text **below** your cursor: `ctrl+shift+end`.

---

*This works in all versions of Sublime Text

Comment: Ok, cool. That works for me. And apparently the linux and windows commands are the same.